# How is public key obtained when creating new CSR with openssl using only private key?

Tags: openssl, certificate, csr

First I create private key with openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.key 1024
```

So I have now private key with passphrase and now create CSR:

```
openssl req -new -key private.key -out CSR.csr
```

However when I display content of this CSR then there is included public key:

```
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (1024 bit)
            Modulus:
```

Where this public key come from if I provided only private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where this public key come from if I provided only private key?

For RSA, the private key is `{n,e,d}`. `n` is the modulus, `e` is the public exponent, and `d` is the private exponent.

There are some additional parameters that can be used to speed up RSA operations, such as `dp` and `dq`, but they aren't strictly needed. And they should be kept private.

For RSA, the public key is `{n,e}`. So the values are always available if you have the private key. `n` is the modulus and `e` is the public exponent as with the private key.

If you somehow manage to lose `e`, you can often recover it because its often a well known value such as 3, 17, or 65537. If you lose `d`, you'll have factor `n` to recover it.